# while creating master detail relationship fields(sharing rule)

Tags: custom-object

what is diffidence between (Read Only: Allows users with at least Read access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records. ) and (Read/Write: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.) any help will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Read Only: Allows users with at least Read access to the Master
>   record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

This option means that ANY user with at lease **READ** permissions on the parent can read, edit, and delete child records

i.e. User has read only to account then they can create, edit, delete all Opportunity records related to the account that they have sharing access to

> Read/Write: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master
>   record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

Is the same as above with the exception that the user would have to have read/write access to the Parent